# Yii ActiveRecord связь в моделях не по primary key

Tags: activerecord, php, yii

Привет всем! 
Есть модели Object, и ObjectUserData.

В модели Object есть поле id, которое является внешним ключем, и есть поле orig_id, которое не является внешним ключем.

В модели ObjectUserData есть поля id(ид записи в таблице), и orig_id(ссылается на orig_id  в модели Object). Мне нужно установить связь "один к одному" таким образом, чтобы из Object можно было получить доступ к записи ObjectUserData по orig_id.

Сделал связь в модели Object так:

```
'userData' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'ObjectUserData', 'orig_id'),
```

Но в результате в запросе получается вот что(приведена часть запроса):

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN `objects_user_data` `userData` 
                    ON ( `userData`.`orig_id` = `t`.`id` )
```

где `t` - псевдоним для таблицы, представленной моделью Objects.

Хотя должно получиться в итоге вот такое:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN `objects_user_data` `userData` 
                    ON ( `userData`.`orig_id` = `t`.`orig_id` )
```

Понимаю, что вопрос нубский, руками бы этот запрос сам написал без проблем, но как это в AR представить - не понимаю :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'userData'=>array(self::HAS_ONE,'ObjectUserData',array('orig_id'=>'id'))
```

ну как-то так. Указать явно какое поле этой модели связать с каким-то полем другой модели.

Comment: Огромнейшее спасибо - то, что доктор прописал!)

Comment: Пжлст, обращайтесь.